# Allowing a user to duplicate a page in an Excel Multi-Page Userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am posting this question here because I actually found another question similar to this one, "Copy Elements From One Page To Another in Multipage with VBA in Excel" I still have questions as I'm not sure how this will work. I would still need to put my data fields into a frame, though.

I need to allow the user to add as many pages as necessary while some of the user's content will move with it and some wil not.

Would it be better to have a field where the user tells the system how many times they need to duplicate it? Or should I just have a button that says, "duplicate this page"

Also, in addition to the UserForm page being duplicated for user input, I need the process to also duplicate the Excel worksheet to assocate with each duplicated page within the Userform.

Help with this will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Set an Upper Cap. i.e A user should not be able to add more than specific number of pages. This would ensure that you don't encounter unforseen errors. For example, The user should not be able to add more than 25 pages (just an example) Remember, Excel is very hungry in terms of memory when it comes to adding unlimited worksheets and hence defining an upper cap is necessary. Also Imagine having say 100 pages in the multipage. It would be too messy.

> Would it be better to have a field where the user tells the system how many times they need to duplicate it? Or should I just have a button that says, "duplicate this page"

I believe you can have both the options. This will ensure that

1. If the user wants to add say 6 pages in one go then the user doesn't have to press the button 6 times.
2. If the user wants to add just one page, then the user can simply click on that button, instead of typing say '1' in a textbox and then clicking on the duplicate button.

> Also, in addition to the UserForm page being duplicated for user input, I need the process to also duplicate the Excel worksheet to assocate with each duplicated page within the Userform.

1. This again is not a problem. You can always use `Worksheets.Add` method to add more sheets
2. You can then set the source of each control on the page to the respective sheets.

Here is a simple example

This will create a copy of the page and also copy the existing textbox to the new page and set it's `ControlSource` property.

**SCREENSHOT**

***BEFORE***

[image]

***AFTER***

[image]

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim pgCount As Long
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim ctl As Control

    '~~> Get the current count of the pages
    pgCount = MultiPage1.Pages.Count

    '~~> Add a new page
    MultiPage1.Pages.Add

    '~~> Change '0' to whatever page you want to copy from
    MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Copy

    '~~> Paste it in the newly created multipage
    MultiPage1.Pages(pgCount).Paste

    '~~> Add a new sheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    '~~> Give the new sheet a name
    wsNew.Name = "Erika"

    '~~> Adding a test value in Range A1 so that it reflects
    '~~> When we set the ControlSource of the textbox
    wsNew.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"

    For Each ctl In MultiPage1.Pages(pgCount).Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            ctl.ControlSource = wsNew.Range("A1").Address
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is another example where instead of copying the control, you can actually create a new control and set it's `ControlSource` property.

**SCREENSHOT**

(Same as above)

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim pgCount As Long
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim ctl As Control

    '~~> Get the current count of the pages
    pgCount = MultiPage1.Pages.Count

    '~~> Add a new page
    MultiPage1.Pages.Add

    '~~> Add a new textbox
    Set ctl = MultiPage1.Pages(pgCount).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", _
    "TextBox" & pgCount)

    '~~> Add a new sheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    '~~> Give the new sheet a name
    wsNew.Name = "Erika"

    '~~> Adding a test value in Range A1 so that it reflects
    '~~> When we set the ControlSource of the textbox
    wsNew.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"

    ctl.ControlSource = wsNew.Range("A1").Address
End Sub
```

Hope this gets you started...